# Why is the blog section of my wordpress site not on Google?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, blogs, web-testing, vs-web-site-project

I recently started a website,(fortunepush.xyz),
I made a seperate sub directory for my blog section and added wordpress to it with Ocean WP theme. I realized that my posts are not coming up on google, site indexing is failing everytime.
I do not understand what is wrong with the site?
Does installing seperate wordpress in my subdirectory affect google somehow?

I just want my posts to show up on google.

The SEO is very well done and properly optimized, also if anyone can check 
can you check if my blog is mobile friendly because it shows up perfectly on my iphone, but google says its not mobile friendly.

The sitemaps are not being indexed too.[This is the sitemap index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF3Q0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have checked "Search Engine Visibility" option in Reading Settings on admin.
The option you will find here in admin side: mydomain.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php

Thanks!